# owncloud 8.02 in ubuntu server 14.04 config.php missing

Tags: php, ubuntu, owncloud

I installed owncloud 8.02 in Ubuntu server 14.04.
Everything is perfect. Except when I tried to change Logo, Title, etc. I found the config.php file is missing from the config folder. Only sample config files are available.
I tried to change files in core/img  core/css folder. nothing works.

I use Filezilla and PuTTy to login and edit files.

Comment: I am using filezilla to edit,upload files and images from windows. my edited css are not updating in browser. when I try to browse 192.168.1.1123/owncloud/core/img/logo-test.png ---- it says not file not found. Permissions same as logo.svg -rw-r--r-- my uploaded files not found in browser –

Answer (score 0):

Sample config files are a pretty common thing to do, it's to avoid sharing sensitive information like database passwords that might be part of the regular config.

You can simply make a copy of it, removing the "sample" part, and then change it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for Clearing that. 
I am using filezilla to edit,upload files and images from windows. my edited css are not updating in browser. when I try to browse http://192.168.1.1123/owncloud/core/img/logo-test.png ---- it says not file not found.
Permissions same as logo.svg     -rw-r--r-- 
my uploaded files not found in browser

Comment: A bit late now, but you can see both the logo and the updated one in FileZilla, but only access the real logo in the browser? Have you tried renaming the real logo to something like logo2.svg and see if it's still available in the browser? If nothing changed you are probably working in the wrong directory.

Comment: thanks for reply. i tried and tested with firebug. its not changing. i can change pre-installed logo. e.g. logo-wide.svg. i think my upload from windows machine through filezilla not accessible. pls help.